# How to make log4j2 create a different log file each time I restart jvm

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to create a different log file each time when I run the java application.
I have the following configuration.
I expected it would create a log file named rf-yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.log which the yyyyMMdd-HHmmss is the time I start the java application. However it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="DEBUG">
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RF" filename="/home/sxd/rfjq/rf.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false" filePattern="/home/sxd/r\ q/rf-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%p] %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <Logger name="model.ModelRF" level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="RF" />
        </Logger>
        <root level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `append="false"` from RollingFile.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your file name is `filename="/home/sxd/rfjq/rf.log` and thus it will create file rf.log. Filename pattern will be used only for rolling strategies, if you use one.
Rename your `filename` with date pattern, ex:

```
filename="/home/sxd/rfjq/rf-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.log"
```

You can as well add "%i" to your filename pattern. This enables "Rollover Strategies" as in [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#Rollover_Strategies), ex:

```
filePattern="/home/sxd/rfjq/rf-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.%i"
```

along with `<OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />` on application startup, would cause file to be created with pattern `rf-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}` but, if such file already exists it would add suffix `.1` to end of file. If there is file with `.1` suffix it will create another with suffix `.2`. You can read more about it in documentation.

Comment: >Rename your filename with date pattern. Doesn't work for me.log4j2 creates file `app-%d{yyMMdd-HHmmss-SSS}.log`

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a bug. I suggest raising this on the Log4j2 [Jira issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2).

---

EDIT: In addition to the OnStartupTriggeringPolicy you need to specify a [TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#TriggeringPolicies).

Answer (score 0):

```
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="10" modulate="true"/>
            **<OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0"/>**
        </Policies>
```

in  FileAppender worked fine for me.